# Creating new instances of CloudTableClient and CloudTable per transaction

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

After doing some research, I am still unsure how best to maintain a 'connection' to Azure Table Storage. Should `CloudTableClient` or `CloudTable` instances be reused across requests?

We are using Table Storage behind a public, high-traffic API. We require high read availability and performance. All queries are POINT queries (both partition key and row key are available) and the response payment is small in size (less than 1 kilobyte). Write performance is not a big concern. Each request on the API could read up to 10 point queries across a few partitions.

From my reading, I have understood the following:

- **`CloudTableClient` is not thread-safe and should be created for every transaction.** Apparently this shouldn't hamper performance when being recreated continuously.
- **A `CloudTable` instance will thus also have to be created for each transaction.**

Are these the correct assumptions to make?

I am thus reinitialising `CloudTableClient` and `CloudTable` for every request. It feels wasteful.

**See implementation:**

```
public class EntityStorageComponent : IEntityComponent
{
    private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

    public CloudTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            ServicePoint tableServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(storageAccount.TableEndpoint);
            tableServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            tableServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;

            var context = new OperationContext();
            context.Retrying += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Retry policy activated");
            };

            // Attempt delays: ~200ms, ~200ms, ~200ms
            var requestOptions = new TableRequestOptions
            {
                RetryPolicy = = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), 3),
                MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
            };

            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("farematrix");
            table.CreateIfNotExists(requestOptions, context);

            return table;                
        }
    }

    public EntityStorageComponent(IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> options)
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(options.Value.TableStorageConnectionString);
    }

    public SomeEntity Find(Guid partitionKey, Guid rowKey)
    {
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SomeEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        var retrievedResult = Table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

        return retrievedResult.Result as SomeEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `I am still unsure how best to maintain a connection to Azure Table Storage.`?

Comment: @GauravMantri: Essentially, should `CloudTableClient` or `CloudTable` instances be reused across requests? I'm concerned about the performance penalty of having to recreate these every single time a request is made (potentially 1000s of times per minute).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apart from the usual overhead of creating an object, I don't see any issue in creating multiple instances of `CloudTableClient` and `CloudTable` objects. So if you're simply doing the following, I don't think you're going to get hit performance wise:

```
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("farematrix");
```

However I do see an issue with the way you're creating `CloudTable` in your code (`Table` member). Essentially in your code, anytime you get the `Table` property from `EntityStorageComponent`, you're trying to create a table in your storage account.

```
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("farematrix");
        table.CreateIfNotExists(requestOptions, context);
```

This is a problem because `table.CreateIfNotExists(requestOptions, context);` will make a network call and would slow down your system considerably. You may want to move out `table.CreateIfNotExists(requestOptions, context);` code and put that in your startup code so that you're always sure (mostly) that the table is present.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks

Comment: Quick question: would you recommend moving the `ServicePoint` amendments to start up as well (Nagles and ConnectionLimit)?

Comment: Yes please. This is system wide setting and should only be defined once.

Comment: Be careful using CreateIfNotExists in anything but single threaded, non-concurrent code.  I've made the mistake of putting this in handler-style code - something like a WCF hander or REST APi handler.  This will cuse multiple threads to run this at once and any thread after the first one will get errors of the sort: "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."